# Help solving $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^2x-\cos 2x}{4x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am lost about what to do with this problem. I am doing $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$ but I am not sure if that is even right or how to get rid of the $4x$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Are you trying to find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos2x}{4x}$?

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying to solve, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: de l'Hopital rule.

Answer (score 1):

Using the trigonometric identity $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ gives us

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos2x}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{4x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x\sin x}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{4}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=(0)(1) =0$$

Answer (score 1):

Using only basic facts:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos2x}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-2\cos^2x+1}{4x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{4x}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using de l'Hospital rule you get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-2\cos x\sin x + 2\sin 2x}4 =0
$$

Comment: could the downvoter care to explain?